# About search a specific day in workbook and set up a pre-noticifcation before that day?

Tags: vba, excel

there is a workbook with many data , the H column is date

I wanna search it by click a button , and the system auto according to "today",and choose the day "after one month" for example now is 11/26/2013 , by clicking the button , the system will choose the data dated 12/26/2013 and pump a msg out.

here is my code , i just wanna store today "day" into a variable and start searching

```
Sub Macro1()
'
Dim oldDate As Date
Dim oldDay As Integer
' Assign a date using standard short format.
oldDate = 2 / 12 / 1969
oldDay = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Day(oldDate)
' oldDay now contains 12.

    Selection.Formula = ""
    Range("H1").Select
    Sheets("Pipeline").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=oldDay, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

and the system said the object missed.

please kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want but try it

```
Sub Main()

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("H1:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If cell = DateAdd("m", 1, Left(Now, 10)) Then
            MsgBox "Cell matches 1 month from today at " & cell.Address
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: oh sorry I would like to ask how to omit the YEAR when doing the searching? for example, in the above case, if today is 26/11/2013 , i cant locate the data dated 26/12/2011 , how to make it possible?

Comment: then replace the last 4 digits of today with the cells year digits