# how to search day from mass data which equal today

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim MyDay As Integer, MyYear As Integer, MyMonth As Integer
    Dim MyDate As Date

    MyDate = Format(MyYear & "/" & MyMonth & "/" & MyDay, "dd/mm/yyyy") < --Error

    Selection.Formula = ""
    Range("M1").Select
    Sheets("Case Settled in 2012").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=MyDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    MsgBox MyDay
End Sub
```

I want to search the data `date=today`

Comment: After posting my answer I noticed you have posted a similar question. But just to be sure. Are they not same?

Comment: @SiddharthRout haha [1 second difference](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20211809/revisions) in between your and mine edits

Comment: @mehow: Hmmm, Here `yDate = Format(MyYear & "/" & MyMonth & "/" & MyDay, "dd/mm/yyyy") < --Error` is highlighted and he wants to search `date=today`

Comment: @SiddharthRout yeah i meant this question revision. there is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208249/about-search-a-specific-day-in-workbook-and-set-up-a-pre-noticifcation-before-th)

Comment: @mehow: Still deciding whether to delete my answer and close this question as an `almost` duplicate or this question is actually different...

Comment: Looked more closely.. they are different.

Comment: oh i am sorry i thought my last question disappeared , so i posted another one , is 2 diff questions ,reli thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MyDate = Format(MyYear & "/" & MyMonth & "/" & MyDay, "dd/mm/yyyy") <--error

What you need is `DateSerial`

```
MyDate = DateSerial(MyYear, MyMonth, MyDay)
```

Also you need to initialize those variables.

**EDIT:**

> I want to search the data date=today

Regarding your 2nd question, @Mehow has already shown you how to loop through a range to do a date comparison in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208249/about-search-a-specific-day-in-workbook-and-set-up-a-pre-noticifcation-before-th). Do a similar comparison here as well and check if the date matches.